# Как изменить данные в Identity User

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

Я создал несколько пользователей в системе. Добавление идет без проблем, а вот редактирование вызывает ошибку

**DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s).**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Edit(ApplicationUser applicationUser)
    {
        IdentityUser user;
        if (ModelState.IsValid && (user = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == applicationUser.Id)) != null)
        {
            user.UserName = applicationUser.UserName;

            //_context.Update(applicationUser);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(applicationUser);
    }
```

Comment: создайте новое [tag:asp.net-mvc] приложение и добавьте туда при помощи менеджера пакетов `nuget` следующий пакет: [Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Samples 2.1.0-alpha1](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples/2.1.0-alpha1), что бы пакет был доступен в списке, не забудьте отметить `Include prerelease`, после этого изучите пример как работать c [tag:asp.net-identity-2]

Comment: я как раз и использую это демо приложение. Там нет возможности редактирования данных юзера

Comment: обратите пристальное внимание на `UserAdminController` в частности метод `Edit` как раз таки редактирует пользователя

Comment: У меня Identity 3. Разницы не будет надеюсь?

Comment: вот про это я Вам затрудняюсь ответить, я использую [tag:asp.net-mvc-identity-2]. посмотрите методы `UserManager` в вашей версии, Вам же все го то надо *обернуть* их в контроллере внутри вашего [tag:asp.net-mvc] приложения

Answer (score 1):

Эта ошибка говорит о том, что не завершен предыдущий запрос в этом же контексте и пытаетесь сделать другой запрос. Если, возможно, используйте короткое время жизни контекста

```
using(var context = new AppContext()){ //..действия с контекстом.../// }
```

Так же возможно что ранее в контексте использовался запрос, результат которого множество и который не завершен методом `.ToList()`, который выполняет запрос.